# MIPS "la" pseudo instruction loads a literal's address

Tags: assembly, printing, int, load, mips

I have two questions here :

1)> What is happening in line 2.The 'la' pseudo instruction refers to load address, instead of the literal '3444' there should have been a label.How can it load the address of the literal

2)> if you replace line 3 with  "li $a0 3444" which loads 3444 into the register #a0 instead of the address.The output is still the same.What i want to ask from this is that how could syscall know that in #a0 is the address of the variable or the variable itself.How could the subroutine for printing the integer work  correctly whether the argument stored in #a0 is the address or the integer value itself.

```
.text

      li $v0 1 
 >>2  la $a0 3444   # When i replace 3444 literal with the label  'anint' it makes sense and the output of course is the same
      syscall


.data

 anint: .word 3444
```

Output:

```
3444
```

UPDATE#2:   I could'nt post the code in a comment so...

IF la(load address) and li(load immediate) both translate to the same instruction i-e loading the literal into #a0 then explain Line 3 from the code segment below.

```
      .text


      li #v0 4
>>3   la #a0 msg  #This loads the address of the label 'msg in #a0' not the label itself    
      syscall





      .data

       msg: .asciiz "This is a long string that can't be saved in the register!"
```

Comment: You shouldn't try to post code in comments anyway.  Editing clarifications into your answer is the correct thing to do.

Comment: labels are addresses.  They aren't "stored" anywhere themselves, they're just useful ways to write addresses symbolically instead of with numeric addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how could syscall know that in #a0 is the address of the variable or the variable itself

It doesn't. System call 1 in SPIM/MARS always prints the *value* in `$a0`.

`li $a0,3444` and `la $a0,3444` are translated into the same thing (some instruction that loads the value `3334` into register `$a0`, such as `ori $a0, $0, 3334`).

Comment: Please refer to the UPDATE on my question.Your answer seems to be conflicting with what i have updated.

Comment: Not at all. A label _is_ an address (well, a symbolic name for some address).

Comment: The conflicting part is in Line 3 from the update code segment where according to your statement  " la #a0 msg " loads the the value within the register #a0 which is impossible as the string value is so... large.Instead it loads the address of the string in #a0.Your answer seems logical to my original question but is conflicting in this case

Comment: There's no conflict. A label is just a symbolic name for an address. `msg` in your case is not a string - it's a name for the address where that string is stored.

Comment: Yeah i am sorry i didn't know what a label was but still ( la $a0,3444) what is it doing? is it trying to put the value 3444 into $a0 or just it's address.If it is putting the literal value 3444 into $a0 then why in case of update#2 it is loading just the address?

Comment: The literal 3444 has no address. In the case of `la $a0,3444` it's behaving the same as `li`, because that's how the person that wrote this assembler chose to implement it.